# How do you sum up ints in a list of list in Python 3?

Tags: python, list, int

```
>>> [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2, 1]]
```

I have this, but I need

```
>>> [5, 7, 5]
```

Can someone help me coding this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?  SO is not meant to do your work for you.  We help with specific issues that you have already tried to solve yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You have to coding something by yourself.

```
>>> [sum(x) for x in a]
[5, 7, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Some functional programming:

```
list(map(sum, a))
```